# Differentiating Chrome browser launched by Selenium chrome driver from manually launched Chrome Browser

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Chrome browser launched by using Selenium chrome driver. Also, there is another Chrome browser launched manually. Both browsers are opening www.google.com. How do I know using Selenium, which one is launched by using the chrome driver? Are there any unique properties that can be obtained from the driver to know the browser that was launched using this driver?

Comment: You question doesn't make sense. A browser launched with Selenium cannot be dissociated from the driver. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: "A browser launched with Selenium cannot be dissociated from the driver" Ok. How about the one I launch manually? This has nothing related to Selenium webdriver?
I want to know, if the browser is running in the foreground or background. I have seen some answers that recommends Javascript which is not helping me.

Comment: a browser launched manually cannot be associated with the driver, unless it was launched in a specific set-up. I still don't get your purpose here. A clear example with steps and expected results would help.

Comment: Agreed, manually launched browser cannot be associated with a driver. What is the difference between a manually launched browser and a browser launched by Selenium driver? eg. Manually launched browser has property "A" which browser launched by Selenium driver does not have. Like the answer provided below, are there some properties? I want this at code-level.

Answer (score 3):

There are some difrrence when the chrome browser is launched by manual and chrome driver
1.when the chrome browser is launched by chrome driver ,the chrome browser will not have any  histort,any addons and any settings
2.if the chrome browser is launched by manual it will have addons or settings or history

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are there ways to find this at code level?

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple Identification, Top Of the Chrome Display Message Its Automated Software ..
See Attached Image [image]

Message is - Chrome is being Controlled by Automated test Software .